How to use action.get_sub_entities() and entity.describe() in ROS2 python launch?
I need to register the event of a node in child launch file as target in parent launch. After I read this answer, I want to try something like:
my_included_launch = IncludeLaunchDescription(...)
sub_entities = my_included_launch.get_sub_entities()
target_node = None
for entity in sub_entities:
   # Somehow identify the node entity maybe with entity.describe()
   if (some check):
      target_node = entity

handler = launch.actions.RegisterEventHandler(
    launch_ros.event_handlers.OnStateTransition(
        target_lifecycle_node=target_node, goal_state='active', ...))

But in my case entity.describe() always return
[ERROR] [launch]: Caught exception in launch (see debug for traceback): 


